# How to specify floating point separator in astropy.io.ascii?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a table, where decimal separator is `,`. When I am trying to read this table using astropy ascii module, the numbers are of `numpy.str_` type.

```
from astropy.io import ascii
data = ascii.read(inputName)
```

If I manually replace `,` to `.` then it's `numpy.float`, which is what I want. Is there any way to tell to astropy.io to use `,` as decimal separator character?

Comment: Could importing as string and then converting later work for you?

Comment: not really, because first of all I know how to do it and second I would like to know that this is possible to do by passing some additional parameter. Since the amount of data is large, converting would take additional resources.